# Run a Principal Component Analysis (PCA) on the dataset to reduce the number of features (components) from 64 to 2

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, scikit-learn

I'm trying to reduce my components to 2 instead of 64 but I keep getting this error:
"Length mismatch: Expected axis has 64 elements, new values have 4 elements"
Why is the PCA I'm running on the data set not changing the number to 2?

This is what I have:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import sklearn.metrics as sm

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


import scipy
from sklearn import decomposition

digits = datasets.load_digits()      #load the digits dataset instead of the iris dataset


x = pd.DataFrame(digits.data)     #was(iris.data)
x.columns = ['Sepal_L', 'Sepal_W', 'Sepal_L', 'Sepal_W']

plt.cla()
pca = decomposition.PCA(n_components=2)
pca.fit(x)
x = pca.transform(x)


y = pd.DataFrame(digits.target)
y.columns = ['Targets']

# this line actually builds the machine learning model and runs the algorithm
# on the dataset
model = KMeans(n_clusters = 10)    #Run k-means on this datatset to cluster the data into 10 classes
model.fit(x)

#print(model.labels_)


colormap = np.array(['red', 'blue', 'yellow', 'black'])

# Plot the Models Classifications
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.scatter(x.Petal_L, x.Petal_W, c=colormap[model.labels_], s=40)
plt.title('K Means Classification')

plt.show()
```

Comment: @sacul Oh ok that makes sense, do you know how I should fix my columns to work for the digits dataset instead?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not actually the PCA that is problematic, but just the renaming of your columns: the `digits` dataset has 64 columns, and you are trying to name the columns according to the column names for the 4 columns in the `iris` dataset.

Because of the nature of the digits dataset (pixels), there isn't really an appropriate naming scheme for the columns. So just don't rename them.

```
digits = datasets.load_digits()      

x = pd.DataFrame(digits.data)     

pca = decomposition.PCA(n_components=2)
pca.fit(x)
x = pca.transform(x)

# Here is the result of your PCA (2 components)
>>> x
array([[ -1.25946636,  21.27488332],
       [  7.95761139, -20.76869904],
       [  6.99192268,  -9.9559863 ],
       ..., 
       [ 10.80128366,  -6.96025224],
       [ -4.87210049,  12.42395326],
       [ -0.34438966,   6.36554934]])
```

Then you can plot the first pc against the second, if that's what you're going for (what I gathered from your code)

```
plt.scatter(x[:,0], x[:,1], s=40)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I was just introduced to data sets today so its all really new to me.

Comment: although, after doing plt.scatter(x[:,0], x[:,1], c=colormap[model.labels_], s=40) I keep getting the error "index 8 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 8"

Comment: Pretty sure that's an issue with your colormap, but I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve TBH